# Was there an Imperial garrison on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars

Was there ever an Imperial garrison (e.g. permanently stationed stormtroopers) on Tatooine, especially at the time of *A New Hope*?

I know that the planet wasn't exactly **controlled** by the Empire, but doesn't mean there weren't some troops stationed there.

I'm looking for a canon answer (even for a "no", ideally)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like there was an Imperial garrison on Tatooine.

[Tour Aryon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tour_Aryon), was Imperial Governor of Tatooine at the time of *A New Hope*. Here an excerpt from her Wookieepedia article:

> When Darth Vader sent his own stormtroopers to the surface of Tatooine to search for R2-D2 and C-3PO, Tour objected, insisting that **her own troops** could handle it. When When Moradmin Bast informed Vader of her objections, Vader did not care.

The scenes where Bast and Vader discussed Aryon's objections were cut from the final film of *A New Hope*, but are still present in the *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope* novel.