# Which worlds were Jedi 'friendly' after Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, order-66

After Order 66 was enacted, many Jedi fled to, fought on or holed up on a planet. Many 'Jedi' locations, i.e. planets with Jedi influence, were raided and the Jedi ruthlessly expunged.

The question is, how far reaching and how stringent was the order? Did they not bother with some back-water/corrupted planets? Did they trust others and not go looking around?

In short, which planets did or could have acted as safe havens for Jedi?

Comment: Vaklin before the Vaklin Insurrection was squashed by Vader

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As for specific planets, I think only [Dagobah](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dagobah) would qualify as *safe* for a Jedi, as the only known sentient being on the planet was an old Jedi Grand Master.

There is also [Alderaan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alderaan#Galactic_Civil_War), where [at least one Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ylenic_It%27kla#Alderaanian_advisor) safely hid for a time, but this had [a bad ending for him and his host](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Destruction_of_Alderaan).

The problem is not really the local population's attitude toward Jedi, but the extent of the Empire's power on those worlds. [Kashyyyk](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kashyyyk#Galactic_Empire_and_Slavery) is a good example: although the locals were sympathetic towards Jedi, most had been enslaved by the Empire.

The only relatively safe place for a Jedi would be beyond the reach of Imperial influence, but the number of worlds under the Empire's control had been increasing; during *A New Hope*, there were more worlds in the Empire than had once been in the Old Republic. Some planets like [Tatooine](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tatooine), where, during *The Phantom Menace*, Republic laws held no power, [had their own governors by  *A New Hope*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9767/was-there-an-imperial-garrison-on-tattooine).

Even if a planet outside of the Empire's influence was found, it would not be safe from denouncement and spies. There was, additionally, the threat of bounty hunters; [Boba Fett](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett) was known to have collected several lightsabers he had taken from Force-sensitives over the course of his bounty hunting career.

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's a pretty bad ending if you ask me...

Answer (score 1):

The planet Jedha from the new film *Rogue One* is a planet filled with kyber crystals. It is also considered to be a religious site for Force-users and Jedi affiliates. Gareth Edwards, the director of *Rouge One* said this at Star Wars Celebration Europe 2016.

Answer (score -3):

None, all of the Jedi either were dead or in hiding. As talked about in the trilogy, the knowledge and use of the force was considered more of a superstition or witchcraft.

Comment: Not useful. Clearly some were safe as Jedi hid there, see the other answer.